# Int entered verificatiion - Parse Server Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, int, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I use the new Parse Server, and in the cloud part which is using Javascript I want to check if an integer is specified by a user, in other words I want to check if the Int is null or not. I can do it for strings, but as I see from comments, an int can not be null. Bu I do not want to change all ints in my code to integers. I try the code below, but it is not working, how can I check if there is a number specified by the user or if it is empty?

```
 if (!req.object.get('number'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as long as `number` isn't zero. To handle that case as well, simply do a type check like this:

`if (typeof req.object.get('number') !== 'number')`.

It seems like you are confusing java and javascript. Javascript does not have ints or integers, only numbers. Javascript variables do not have types and all variables can be `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you Simon, you are saving me these days:)